# who know android Parcelable efficiency when used intent.putExtra()

Tags: android

I have a problem.

When I send a object' infomation to another activity by intent. I used the implement parcelable Object or(serialization) or a key-value bundle that every the object's field.

Which way is best?

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550670/benefit-of-using-parcelable-instead-of-serializing-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion at http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e97689f91d3b9005?fwc=2

> Serializable is slow largely because
>   it is super general and completely
>   deals with backwards compatibility,
>   object references, automatically saves
>   fields for you (reflection is slooow),
>   etc.  Parcelable is fast because it
>   does none of these things, and thus is
>   only suitable for IPC and not
>   persistent storage.

Answer (score 0):

I think that its not a question of which is better. Passing the data thought a Bundle is useful when all you want is the data, a Parcelable is useful when you want to act on the data (i.e. call methods) because it allows for a full object reconstruction.