# Serialization/deserialization possibilities

Tags: android, serialization

What are the possibilities in Android, when I intend to use serialization/deserialization with data? Which one serialization/deserialization solution is the best for distant serialization/deserialization (e.g. on server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard Java serialization (implement `Serializable` interface) or serialize your data in JSON/XML form and save in files in device memory or external storage (SD card).
Also you can use SQLite databases.

`Parcelable` is not intented to use for data storage. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550670/benefit-of-using-parcelable-instead-of-serializing-object/5610428#5610428).

References: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Thanks Sergey, and do you know which is the best for internal serialization (data from one class to another) and for distant serialization (XML, JSON or any custom)?

Comment: For internal usage `Serializable` is enough in simple cases. If you'll have problems with speed of serialization, then you need to implement custom serialization (link in answer). JSON/XML serialization is slower than standard, but it is optimal solution for sending data over the network (particularly JSON; it is smaller in size).