# Is parcelable worth to implement to pass data between activities?

Tags: android, performance, serialization, parcelable

I want to improve the performance of my app. One thing which comes to my mind is to replace all the serializable intent-bundle parameters with parcelable.

I found this thread: [Benefit of using Parcelable instead of serializing object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550670/benefit-of-using-parcelable-instead-of-serializing-object)

There somebody states, from a book, that parcelable is only meant to be used for interprocess communication? That's probably not up to date, anymore, right? Because it is, technically at least, possible.

Then there's also the statement that parcelable is not reliable because the implementation varies accross devices, this would be of course a killing characteristic, since I want it to work always, all devices and apis, starting from API 7.

And I also read some advices about using Externalizable or implementing a custom protocol... but I don't understand, why Parcelable is not reliable, why Android developers do such buzz around something which will not work on all devices? Or is the comment not true?

Is it worth to implement Parcelable? Do I stick with Serializable? Or is a custom serialization / Externalizable the right approach?

Please don't tell me "just try", I don't have time for this, specially to check if Parcelable is reliable (and also not enough devices)... experience is asked...

Thanks.

P.S. Also don't say me "Serializable will be acceptable for most cases" I know that, it's indeed acceptable but I have time and would like to use it with Parcelable (or something else), if this improves the user experience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Parcelable` works always, all the time, on all devices. If it didn't, **nothing** would work. Android internals rely very heavily on `Parcelable`.

`Parcelable` will be a bit more efficient than `Serializable` but I seriously doubt that it would have much impact on your "user experience" (unless, of course, you are using it all over the place and serializing very large and complicated objects).

If you think you are having performance issues, then I would spend my available time profiling the application and gathering empirical data about where it is spending its time. IMHO replacing `Serializable` with `Parcelable` is a relatively low-level implementation optimization that is likely to give you close to zero perceivable performance improvement.

Comment: Currently I'm not having performance issues, I just thought that faster parameter passing would make screen switch quicker such that the app feels lighter and faster. Quick and responsive is something I consider very important for the user experience.

Comment: I'm not passing huge amounts of data, but also not a few primitives... I'm passing things like user-object (1), with lots of personal data, or account, things like that.

Answer (score 4):

> There somebody states, from a book, that parcelable is only meant to be used for interprocess communication? That's probably not up to date, anymore, right? Because it is, technically at least, possible.

If Parcelable was not meant to be passed between activities, why does the [putExtra (String name, Parcelable value)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable%29) Intent method exists since API Level 1?

> Then there's also the statement that parcelable is not reliable because the implementation varies accross devices, this would be of course a killing characteristic, since I want it to work always, all devices and apis, starting from API 7.

Let my quote the [Parcel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html) documentation:

> Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism. This class (and the corresponding Parcelable API for placing arbitrary objects into a Parcel) is designed as a *high-performance IPC transport*. As such, it is not appropriate to place any Parcel data in to **persistent storage**: changes in the underlying implementation of any of the data in the Parcel can render older data unreadable.

Here I can only read an advice about not storing a Parcel data into persistent storage. 
From my personal experience Parcelable was never an issue for passing data between activities. I heavily use it and support API 8 to current API.

Concerning performance and speed it's established that using Parcelable is better, as it is an Android specific *high-performance IPC transport* serialization mechanism. Though, in order to actually see an improvement, it should depends on how much you use it.

Comment: Well, I also saw that it's possible to pass it, and even had already tested it, but got confused by that thread -> " That is, the Parcelable is not meant to be passed to an activity. If you want to start an activity and pass it some data, use a bundle. Parcelable is meant to be used only as part of an AIDL definition." And other posts saying it's not reliable.

Comment: Bundle also provides a putParcelable() method. By the way, Intents and Bundles are one type of IPC (Inter-Process Communication) mechanism, so using them suits the way Parcelable is designed for.

Comment: Yes I know but you understand that it's confusing an accepted answer with 26 votes (and 100 bounty) saying "Parcelable is NOT MEANT TO BE PASSED TO AN ACTIVITY". As said I already tried this and it works, but that thread made me doubt.