# Serializable crash error when loading web broser from my application

Tags: android, serialization

I'm developing an application.

This application contains 2 classes

- Discovery class which implements serializable
- Main class which extends Activity

In the Main class I call the android web browser on a click on the button in the application interface . And this behaviour generate a crash.

bellow is the code:

**MainTest.java**

```
package com.heeere.androiddnssd.discovery;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainTest extends Activity {

    android.net.wifi.WifiManager.MulticastLock lock;
    private Discovery discovery; 
    private TextView textView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if ( savedInstanceState == null)
            discovery = new Discovery(this);
        else
            discovery = (Discovery) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("discovery");
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        textView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.text);
        Button b = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //discovery.setUp();
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        });

        android.net.wifi.WifiManager wifi = (android.net.wifi.WifiManager) getSystemService(android.content.Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        lock = wifi.createMulticastLock("mylockthereturn");
        lock.setReferenceCounted(true);
        lock.acquire();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
        outState.putSerializable("discovery", discovery);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    public void updateView () {
        String msg = discovery.getMsg();
        textView.setText(msg);
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        discovery.stop();
        lock.release();
        super.onStop();
    }


}
```

**Discovery.java**

```
package com.heeere.androiddnssd.discovery;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.jmdns.JmDNS;
import javax.jmdns.ServiceEvent;
import javax.jmdns.ServiceListener;

public class Discovery implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 637576886455091135L;
    private String type = "_ikunet._tcp.local.";
    private String msg="";
    private JmDNS jmdns = null;
    private ServiceListener listener = null;
    private MainTest maintest;
    android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();

    public Discovery (MainTest maintest) {
        this.maintest = maintest;
        setUp();
    }

    public void setUp() {

        try {
            jmdns = JmDNS.create();
            jmdns.addServiceListener(type, listener = new ServiceListener() {

                public void serviceResolved(ServiceEvent ev) {
                    msg = msg + ev.getInfo().getName()+ "\n";
                    update();
                }

                public void serviceRemoved(ServiceEvent ev) {
                }

                public void serviceAdded(ServiceEvent event) {
                    jmdns.requestServiceInfo(event.getType(), event.getName(), 1);
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    private void update() {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                maintest.updateView();
            }
        }, 1);
    }


    public void stop() {
        if (jmdns != null) {
            if (listener != null) {
                jmdns.removeServiceListener(type, listener);
                listener = null;
            }
            jmdns.unregisterAllServices();
            try {
                jmdns.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            jmdns = null;
        }
    }

}
```

**LogCat**

```
09-13 15:08:30.507: E/AndroidRuntime(15775): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.heeere.androiddnssd.discovery.Discovery)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1131)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1085)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:469)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1445)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:483)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityPaused(ActivityManagerNative.java:1427)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3106)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:119)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775): Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.os.Handler
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1854)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1696)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1660)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:1153)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:420)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1251)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1587)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1854)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1696)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1660)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1126)
09-13 15:08:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(15775):    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is due to pass main activity to serializable class when creating its related object. in our case passing the `MainTest` Object to the `Discovery` object when creating it.
The solution: create another serializable class which contains all Discovery data (data to be serialzable).

Answer (score -1):

The error is pretty clear: `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.os.Handler`

Figure out how to take the handler out: `android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();`

Comment: You should probably create another class that has just your data, without any extra logic.

Comment: I m new be in android and java. is it possible to be more specific or give me an example

Comment: the crash cause is not the handler. please refer to this link to see the rel problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411012/crash-due-to-passing-context-to-a-serializable-class

Comment: Errr... of course! You can't serialize an Activity either! <Sigh>

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know Serializable is slow on Android, you should use Parcelable instead, see this link for more info: [Benefit of using Parcelable instead of serializing object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550670/benefit-of-using-parcelable-instead-of-serializing-object)

Regards