# crash due to passing context to a serializable class

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serializable crash error when loading web broser from my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408386/serializable-crash-error-when-loading-web-broser-from-my-application)

below a code causing a crash when I try to open a web browser from my application by a click on the button on the interface

**MainTest.java**

```
package com.heeere.androiddnssd.discovery;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainTest extends Activity {

    private Discovery discovery; 

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if ( savedInstanceState == null)
            discovery = new Discovery(this);
        else
            discovery = (Discovery) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("discovery");
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button b = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
        outState.putSerializable("discovery", discovery);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

**Discovery.java**

```
package com.heeere.androiddnssd.discovery;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Discovery implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 637576886455091135L;
    private MainTest maintest;
    //android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();

    public Discovery (MainTest maintest) {
        this.maintest = maintest;
    }

}
```

Now, If I remove the MainTest Class type from the constructor of Discovery, the bug will disappear. **So that's the cause of the crash.**

How to fix this problem without removing the MainTest Class type from the constructor of Discovery?

Comment: you havent implemented all methods of  serializable

Comment: no, how to do it? and will fix the problem ?

Comment: Repeated question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408386/serializable-crash-error-when-loading-web-broser-from-my-application/12409008#12409008

Comment: it's the same question, but here I know the crash cause and I provided a simple code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is due to pass main activity to serializable class when creating its related object. in our case passing the `MainTest` Object to the `Discovery` object when creating it.
The solution: create another serializable class which contains all Discovery data (data to be serialzable).