# How to pass an object of a class using an intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

How to pass an `object` of a `class` using an `intent`?

ex.

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
```

how can I pass `mc` using an `intent`?

Comment: http://androidhub.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/android-intents-for-passing-data-between-activities-part-3/ check the link

Comment: @codeMagic Why would you edit my question for nothing?

Comment: All I did was put the code and variable/object names in code brackets. Makes it easier to read. I can change it back if it offends you. But it doesn't harm you...just improves readability of question

Comment: @codeMagic Sorry about it! yeah I just realized it!

Comment: Ok, no problem...still friends

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **You need to use Android Parcelable**

### What is a Parcel:

> - Parcel is a light weight IPC (Inter Process Communication) data structure, where you can flatten your objects in byte stream.
> - Parcelable is an Android specific interface where you implement the serialization yourself. It was created to be far more efficient that
>     Serializable, and to get around some problems with the default Java
>     serialization scheme.

### How to use Parcelable :

> 1.Implement an Interface android.os.Parcelable which will make Objects of Parcelable class.
>
> 2.Overwrite two methods of android.os.Parcelable Interface as bellow :
>
> - describeContents()- define the kind of object you are going to Parcel.
> - writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)- actual object serialization/flattening happens here. You need to individually Parcel
>     each element of the object.
>
> 3.Define a variable called CREATOR of type Parcelable.Creator

### Check this tutorial :

> http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html

### Parcelable vs Serialization

> - Serialization in Java is far +too slow+ to satisfy Android’s interprocess-communication requirements. So the team built the
>     Parcelable solution. The Parcelable approach requires that you
>     explicitly serialize the members of your class, but in the end, you
>     get a much faster serialization of your objects.
> - The problem with Serializable is that it tries to appropriately handle everything under the sun and uses a lot reflection to make
>     determine the types that are being serialized.

Comment: +1. I will give you again +1 but its not possible.. Android framework also uses Parcelable objects..

Comment: Adding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550670/benefit-of-using-parcelable-instead-of-serializing-object for more details..

Answer (score 2):

Use Serializable Object, and Keep it inside Bundle or Intent Directly

**Sending Object**

```
    Intent mIntent=new Intent();
    mIntent.putExtra("iis",new MyClass());
```

and your class

```
    private class MyClass implements Serializable{

}
```

**Getting at other End**

```
MyClass mc=(MyClass) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("iis");
```

**Updated**

you can send data as Parcelable object also. But remember

If you are sending a **non-primitive** type data/Object to another activity through the intent you have to either Serialize or implement Parcelable for that object. The preferred technique is Parcelable since it `doesn't impact the performance`

Comment: That was not wrong definition, you can send Parcel able object also.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29671/discussion-between-sameer-and-pankaj-kumar)

Answer (score 0):

One option could be let your  class implement Serializable interface and then you can pass object instances in intent extra using putExtra(Serializable..) variant of the Intent#putExtra() method.

```
Passing :
   intent.putExtra("MyClassObject", obj);  

To retrive 
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClassObject");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class:

```
 public class myClassObject implements Serializable {

      public myClassObject(){

      }
 }
```

intent passing:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("question_data", qData);
    intent.putExtra("answer_string", answer);
    startActivity(intent);
```