# How do I get a class object to operate with from Serializable?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, serialization

I have an app where I am trying to pass class objects between activities. This is how I'm doing it.

Class:

```
public class Player implements Serializable{
    public String name;
    public int score;
    public static final int serialVersionUID = 12345;
}
```

Putting class object to intent extra:

```
private TextView createNewTextView (String text){
    final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final TextView newTextView = new TextView(this);

    newTextView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    newTextView.setText(text);

    Player newPlayer = new Player();
    newPlayer.name = text;
    newPlayer.score = 0;
    players.add(text);
    playerScores.add(newPlayer);
    zacniIgro.putExtra("playerScores", (ArrayList<Player>) playerScores);
    zacniIgro.putStringArrayListExtra("players", (ArrayList<String>) players);
    return newTextView;
}
```

Getting intent extras in another activity:

```
playersData = getIntent();
playerScoresData = getIntent();
players = playersData.getStringArrayListExtra("players");
playerScores = (ArrayList<Player>) playerScoresData.getSerializableExtra("playerScores");
```

How do I now operate with those serializable objects? I want to get a certain element from playerScores and operate with it. For example: I want to get the element out of it that is at index 0 and then operate with it's name and score.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are asking: `playerScores.get(0)` will get you a `Player` object. `playerObj.name` and `playerObj.score` will get you its name and score.

Comment: On Android you should be using Parcelable, not Serializable

Comment: @user2558882 but how do I assing that "playerScores.get(0)" to a Player object?

Comment: `Player playerObj = playerScores.get(0);`. To get the name: `String nameOfPlayer = playerObj.name;`. To get the score: `int scoreForPlayer = playerObj.score`.

Comment: @user2558882 thank you very much! that's what I was looking for. You can post it as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Thansk for suggesting, I will take a look into it. But why is Parcelable better than Serializable for Android? What's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
playerScores = (ArrayList<Player>) playerScoresData.getSerializableExtra("playerScores");
```

To get a `Player` object from `playerScores`:

```
Player playerObj = playerScores.get(index);
```

Player's name can accessed by:

```
String nameOfPlayer = playerObj.name;
```

To get the score:

```
int scoreForPlayer = playerObj.score;
```

As Marcin has suggested, use `Parcelable` in place of `Serializable`. Serialization is extremely slow. A comparison: [Parcelable vs Serializable](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/)

More here: [Benefit of using Parcelable instead of serializing object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5551155/2558882)