# Should I make a class both serializable and parcelable?

Tags: android, parcelable, serializable, parcel

I have just created a class for an android application that I am currently making. I made it parcelable so that I can efficiently send objects of this class between activities.  However, I would also like to save these objects to internal storage.  From what I have read I need to make the class serilizable in order to do so.  Is there some other efficient way that I can save these objects or is it fine to make the class serializable as well?

Answer (score 0):

[Perceable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) is for Inter Process Communication which faster compare the Serializable. From your requirement seems like [serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) is good enough.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550670/benefit-of-using-parcelable-instead-of-serializing-object) and Android doc for more details.