# Parse List<> or 'Delegate' to intent

Tags: android, android-intent, delegates, tableview

I have a TableView and I'm showing a DetailView if a cell is clicked (I'm starting a new intent).
In this DetailView you can alter the data or add a new data entry.

So I have to parse the data to the new intent and notify my TableView if Data is added changed in order to update the TableView and of course I have to save the data.

Parsing the data to the intent is quite 'complicated' compared to other languages but no problem. But how do I notifiy my TableView that data is changed or added?

In C++, iOS or C# I would use a delegate, but Java has no delegates. So, what is the way to go in Java/Android?

Another question:
If there is no easy way to tell the TableView that data has changed I'd like to parse a List<> of my data to the DetailView, so the DetailView can handle the save operations.

Do I really need to create a own subclass of List<> and implement the Parcelable interface? Is there really no easier way to achieve this?

Right now I have implemented the DetailView to add a new component like this:

```
    ((Button)view.findViewById(R.id.cmdNewMemory)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MemoryDetailsFragmentActivity.class);
// Parse enum to tell the DetailView if new data is to be added or old data is to be changed
            intent.putExtra("MEMORYDETAILSTYPE", (Parcelable)MEMORYDETAILSTYPE.New);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I have to parse the data to the new intent and notify my TableView if Data is added changed in order to update the TableView and of course I have to save the data.

There are several ways of passing more complex data to activites:

- simply passing identifiers if your data is backed by a database
- implementing `Parcelable`
- implementing `Serializable`
- passing the data through a static singleton
- passing the data through an instance of [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

Related discussions:

- [Benefit of using Parcelable instead of serializing object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550670/benefit-of-using-parcelable-instead-of-serializing-object)
- [Singletons vs. Application Context in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826905/singletons-vs-application-context-in-android)

---

A pragmatic approach for updating your table view would be to just redraw it `onResume()` of the containing activity - either unconditionally or for instance triggered by a new last modified date. In a more sophisticated approach one could modify the elements of the data structure within that table's adapter implementation using its built-in methods (such as `insert()` and `remove()` in case of `ArrayAdapter`) and finally calling its [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29).