# How does Bundle works?

Tags: android, android-bundle

I'm not asking how do I use it nor what does it do, how does it **works**. The question came to me when I though why didn't they just put a `putExtra(String,Object)` so I can pass an object. Obviously they just didn't forgot to do it, rather than the way Bundle works isn't one you can *just* do that.

PS: `Serializable` or `Parcelable` is something you cannot implement on every class you create, so they are not a replacement for `putExtra(String,Object)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Obviously they just didn't forgot to do it

Correct.

A `Bundle` itself is `Parcelable`, as Doctoror Drive notes. The point behind a `Parcelable` is to be able to place it into a `Parcel`, and the point behind a `Parcel` is to pass the data across process boundaries. You cannot pass arbitrary objects across process boundaries, just as you cannot write arbitrary objects to a file and cannot stream arbitrary objects over a socket.

Comment: So the thing is you're actually passing data between processes. I had the idea that you were just passing data between activity subclasses, not processes themselves. Is it considered "hack-ish" to implement `Parcelable` on model(or entity) classes to pass them between activities rather than passing the ID and querying a database?

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco: "I had the idea that you were just passing data between activity subclasses, not processes themselves" -- it is possible that the sender and receiver are both in the same process, but usually the `Parcel` goes by way of another process. For example, all `startActivity()` calls go by way of an OS process, even if you are starting one of your own activities. With regards to "hack-ish", I tend to recommend pass-by-reference (ID) versus pass-by-copy (`Parcelable`), though both have their places.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, a *parcelable* or *serializable* class are "transformed" in generic binaries with your package reference. This able you to transfer and persist data over databases, `Intents` and more.

The idea behind this is keep the state of some `Activity` or `Fragment` for example as a state machine.

> By default, the system uses the Bundle instance state to save
>   information about each View object in your activity layout (such as
>   the text value entered into an EditText object). So, if your activity
>   instance is destroyed and recreated, the state of the layout is
>   restored to its previous state with no code required by you. However,
>   your activity might have more state information that you'd like to
>   restore, such as member variables that track the user's progress in
>   the activity.

Read more at [Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).

**[Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html)**

> By default, the serialization mechanism encodes an object's class
>   name, the names of its non-transient fields (including non-public
>   fields), and the values of all of those fields. **The output is an
>   opaque sequence of bytes.** Those bytes can be decoded into a new,
>   equivalent instance as long as the decoder has compatible versions of
>   the originating classes. Changing the class name, field names or field
>   types breaks serialization compatibility and complicates
>   interoperability between old and new versions of the serializable
>   class. Adding or removing fields also complicates serialization
>   between versions of a class because it requires your code to cope with
>   missing fields.

Read more at: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html

**[Parcel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html)**

> The bulk of the Parcel API revolves around **reading and writing data of
>   various types**.

Read more at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Bundle documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

**More links and posts**

- http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/
- http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/
- [Benefit of using Parcelable instead of serializing object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550670/benefit-of-using-parcelable-instead-of-serializing-object)

Hope helped.

Answer (score 0):

`Bundle` implements `Parcelable` so all the objects you pass must be valid for a `Parcel`, otherwise. Bundle can't be used passed as a `Parcelable`.

Comment: This is not what I asked, I want to know how does `Bundle` works internally, so that you can't just pass an `Object`

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco `Bundle` is passed as a `Parcelable` it puts all your values to a `Parcel` when passed between Components. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not asking how do I use it nor what does it do, how does it works.

`Bundle` implements `Parcelable`, so it has to pass `Objects` to a `Parcel`. I would assume that `Bundles` are backed by `HashMaps` given their key, value nature.

> Obviously they just didn't forgot to do it, rather than the way Bundle
>   works isn't one you can just do that.

You are right. They have not forgot it. `Bundles` can be used to do IPC (Inter Process Communication), so the system needs to know how to recreate an `Object`, hence `Bundle` implements `Parcelable`. This makes you confine to the same paradigm. If you have a custom `Object` it has to be able to tell Android how to re-construct itself across processes; hence it needs to implement `Parcelable`.