# I want to pack an enum value in a Bundle and get as enum

Tags: android

I have this enum like this

```
  enum Status {READY, DISCONNECTED, RECEIVING, ... more }
```

I want to send a value of this enum over to another thread via a Bundle.

The other thread would like to extract enum value from the Bundle ,

How can this be done , smartly ?

```
   Bundle createBundle(Status status);
```

and

```
   Status getStatus(Bundle b);
```

Thanks,

Comment: You can't.  Think of an enum as a shortcut way to create a class.  It has no "instance" and it's therefore meaningless to bundle it.  You could bundle the type and pass that but that doesn't give you anything.  Are you perhaps wanting to pass an enum value?  Actually, what *are* you trying to do?

Comment: Ah,. just seen the title.  Please edit your question to make it explicit that you are trying to pass an enum value, not the enum itself, and accepts Todd's answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to put an Enum in a Bundle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293020/android-how-to-put-an-enum-in-a-bundle)

Comment: Easier way: [Android: How to put an Enum in a Bundle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293020/android-how-to-put-an-enum-in-a-bundle/38764715#38764715)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Good question!  I'm not aware of a way to pack enums directly.  I always use this to pack:

```
int intValue = myEnum.ordinal();
```

then this to unpack:

```
MyEnum enumValue = MyEnum.values()[intValue];
```

Answer (score 35):

Since Enum is serializable, we can just pack the enum into the bundle using:

```
public static String MY_ENUM = "MY_ENUM";
myBundle.putSerializable(MY_ENUM, enumValue);
```

To retrieve, use:

```
MyEnum myEnum = (MyEnum) myBundle.getSerializable(MY_ENUM);
```