# ENUM IllegalArgumentException during Deserialization

Tags: xml, soap, enums, deserialization

I'm sending XML Request for field CURRENT_BUSINESS which is an ENUM value. What should be the possible value such that it deserializes. 
I'm getting this exception:

```
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
com.edu.service.provider.prime.entity.studentInfo._2012;
    at com.edu.service.provider.prime.entity.studentInfo._2012.BusinessCode_Enum.fromValue(BusinessCode_Enum.java:33)
    at com.edu.service.provider.prime.entity.studentInfo._2012.BusinessCode_Enum.fromString(BusinessCode_Enum.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.EnumDeserializer.makeValue(EnumDeserializer.java:53)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.onEndElement(SimpleDeserializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializerImpl.endElement(DeserializerImpl.java:502)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:171)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:81)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**ENUM implementation:**

```
/**
 * BusinessCode_Enum.java
 *
 * This file was auto-generated from WSDL
 * by the Apache Axis 1.4 Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT) WSDL2Java emitter.
 */

    package com.edu.service.provider.prime.entity.studentInfo._2012;

    public class BusinessCode_Enum implements java.io.Serializable {
        private java.lang.String _value_;
        private static java.util.HashMap _table_ = new java.util.HashMap();

        // Constructor
        protected BusinessCode_Enum(java.lang.String value) {
            _value_ = value;
            _table_.put(_value_,this);
        }

        public static final java.lang.String _CURRENT_BUSINESS = "CURRENT_BUSINESS";
        public static final java.lang.String _NEXT_BUSINESS = "NEXT_BUSINESS";
        public static final java.lang.String _CLIENT = "CLIENT";
        public static final java.lang.String _PREV_BUSINESS = "PREV_BUSINESS";
        public static final BusinessCode_Enum CURRENT_BUSINESS = new BusinessCode_Enum(_CURRENT_BUSINESS);
        public static final BusinessCode_Enum NEXT_BUSINESS = new BusinessCode_Enum(_NEXT_BUSINESS);
        public static final BusinessCode_Enum CLIENT = new BusinessCode_Enum(_CLIENT);
        public static final BusinessCode_Enum PREV_BUSINESS = new BusinessCode_Enum(_PREV_BUSINESS);
        public java.lang.String getValue() { return _value_;}
        public static BusinessCode_Enum fromValue(java.lang.String value)
              throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException {
            BusinessCode_Enum enumeration = (BusinessCode_Enum)
                _table_.get(value);
            if (enumeration==null) throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException();
            return enumeration;
        }
        public static BusinessCode_Enum fromString(java.lang.String value)
              throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException {
            return fromValue(value);
        }
        public boolean equals(java.lang.Object obj) {return (obj == this);}
        public int hashCode() { return toString().hashCode();}
        public java.lang.String toString() { return _value_;}
        public java.lang.Object readResolve() throws java.io.ObjectStreamException { return fromValue(_value_);}
        public static org.apache.axis.encoding.Serializer getSerializer(
               java.lang.String mechType, 
               java.lang.Class _javaType,  
               javax.xml.namespace.QName _xmlType) {
            return 
              new org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.EnumSerializer(
                _javaType, _xmlType);
        }
        public static org.apache.axis.encoding.Deserializer getDeserializer(
               java.lang.String mechType, 
               java.lang.Class _javaType,  
               javax.xml.namespace.QName _xmlType) {
            return 
              new org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.EnumDeserializer(
                _javaType, _xmlType);
        }
        // Type metadata
        private static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc typeDesc =
            new org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc(BusinessCode_Enum.class);

        static {
            typeDesc.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://service.edu.com/provider/prime/entity/studentInfo/2012/", "BusinessCode_Enum"));
        }
        /**
         * Return type metadata object
         */
        public static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc getTypeDesc() {
            return typeDesc;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static java.util.HashMap _table_ = new java.util.HashMap();
```

needs to be:

```
private static java.util.HashMap<String, BusinessCode_Enum> _table_ = new java.util.HashMap<String, BusinessCode_Enum>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the custom fields in your enum (for example `_table_`) are not serialized at all. See [this answer to the question "Is custom enum Serializable too?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15522276/162684)