# Broadcast intent with enum: Parcelable encounteredClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object

Tags: android, enums

I send Broadcast intent with enum ，then onReceiver the action

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.coagent.intent.action.test")
 intent.putExtra("Key_state", KeyState.NONE);
 MainActivity.this.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

enum as follow：

```
 public static enum KeyState {
    NONE,
    DOWN,
    UP
}
```

then other app onReceive the Broadcast,handler the intent

```
  String EXTRA_KEY_STATE="Key_state";
  Serializable keyState = intent.getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_KEY_STATE);
    String ks = ((Enum) keyState).toString();
    LogUtils.i(TAG, "Wjc handerChangAnAction: ks=" + ks);
    if (null != ks && !ks.equals("NONE")) {
        return;
    }
```

but onReceive ation  it immediately crashes with

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.wjc.wecarnews, PID: 25775
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver 
com.wjc.wecarnews.system.PlayReceiver: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Parcelable encounteredClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object 
(name = com.rhr.wjc.demo.MainActivity$KeyState)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2414)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:805)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:621)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Whats the value of this EXTRA_KEY_STATE.

Comment: Are the sender and the recipient in the same app? Also, bear in mind that implicit broadcasts are largely banned on Android 8.0+.

Comment: Fixed unnecessary indents.

Answer (score -1):

It's not recommended to pass `Enum` values through `Intent`.
[see explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15522276/7317083)

Alternatively, you can do the following:

When you are sending `Intent`:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.coagent.intent.action.test")
 intent.putExtra("Key_state", KeyState.NONE.ordinal());
 MainActivity.this.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

When you are receiving `Intent`:

```
int ordinal = intent.getIntExtra("Key_state",-1);
String ks = KeyState.values()[ordinal].toString();
LogUtils.i(TAG, "Wjc handerChangAnAction: ks=" + ks);
if (null != ks && !ks.equals("NONE")) {
   return;
}
```

P.S. using `Enums` not recommended in android at all
[read this article](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-performance-avoid-using-enum-on-android-326be0794dc3)

Comment: [Enums are serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521309/is-custom-enum-serializable-too).