# How to make map an enum to database table?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

question simillary to this one:
[JPA Enum type as table in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590640/jpa-enum-type-as-table-in-database)

I have enum like this:

```
public enum OrderStatus {

    CREATED(0, true), 
    DRIVER_ASSIGNED(2, false), 
    ROUTE_ASSIGNED(4, false), 

    SUCCESSFULLY_FINISHED(20, true),

    CANCELLED(100, true);

    @Id
    final int id;
    final boolean visibleForClient;

    OrderStatus(int id, boolean visibleForClient) {
        this.id = id;
        this.visibleForClient = visibleForClient;
    }
}
```

and want to see it as a table like this:

---

```
| ORDER STATUS         | ID | IS_VISIBLE_FOR_CLIENT |
|----------------------|----|-----------------------|
| CREATED              |  0 | TRUE                  |
| DRIVER_ASSIGNED      |  2 | FALSE                 |
| ROUTE_ASSIGNED       |  4 | FALSE                 |
| SUCCESSFULLY_FINISHED| 20 | TRUE                  |
| CANCELLED            |100 | TRUE                  |
```

Comment: I think the best approach is to use custom converter or UserType.

Comment: Your approach is strange. If I look at the database table, I see an entity with three field: `id`, `orderStatus`, `isVisibleForClient` but your `enum` does not reflect that: either the `id`, `visibleForClient` must not be here, either you are writing the entity class but then it must not be an enum.

Comment: Why would you need a table if you have an enum already? It is better to have one or the other to store this information.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for initial data entry to your table with the above data.

1. You could create above table structure by the following code

   ```
   @Entity
   public class OrderTracker {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private int id;

   @Column(name = "IS_VISIBLE_FOR_CLIENT")
   private boolean visibleForClient;

   @Column(name = "ORDER_STATUS")
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private OrderStatus orderStatus;

   public OrderTracker(int id, boolean visibleForClient, OrderStatus orderStatus) {
       this.id = id;
       this.visibleForClient = visibleForClient;
       this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
   }


   //setter & getter 

   public enum OrderStatus {

       CREATED(0, true),
       DRIVER_ASSIGNED(2, false),
       ROUTE_ASSIGNED(4, false),
       SUCCESSFULLY_FINISHED(20, true),
       CANCELLED(100, true);

       final int id;
       final boolean visibleForClient;
       OrderStatus(int id, boolean visibleForClient) {
           this.id = id;
           this.visibleForClient = visibleForClient;
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. To create initial data on the table you could use flyway or liquibase.