# Android getting value from selected radiobutton

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a piece of code with three `RadioButton`s within a `RadioGroup`. I want to set an `onCheckedListener` that will show the value of the `RadioButton` in a `Toast`. However what I have gotten so far is not working. How do I get the value of the `RadioButton` and display it in a `Toast`? This is my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    RadioGroup rg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        final String value =
            ((RadioButton)findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()))
            .getText().toString();

        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="152dp" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Choose 1" />

         <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Choose 2" />

         <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Choose 3" />
     </RadioGroup>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Tested and working. Check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

  private RadioGroup radioGroup;
  private RadioButton radioButton;
  private Button btnDisplay;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    addListenerOnButton();

  }

  public void addListenerOnButton() {

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio);
    btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

    btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            // find the radiobutton by returned id
            radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

            Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
                radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });

  }
}
```

xml

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioMale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_male" 
            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_female" />

    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: This is the thing u have seen from mykong link...instead of using button how can we get the selected id..for multiple radio group.

Comment: Perfect!!! answer... easy to get radio button view, when user will click !!

Comment: Element with ID btnDisplay does not appear in your XML.

Answer (score 107):

In case, if you want to do some job on the selection of one of the radio buttons (without having any additional OK button or something), your code is fine, updated little.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
        {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch(checkedId){
                    case R.id.radio0:
                        // do operations specific to this selection
                        break;
                    case R.id.radio1:
                        // do operations specific to this selection
                        break;
                    case R.id.radio2:
                        // do operations specific to this selection
                        break;
                }   
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a small correction, a very small one rather, you have declared 'rg' twice. It wont make a difference at all, just makes the code more readable.

Comment: @kaps faced this issue in api_31: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092712/switch-case-statement-error-case-expressions-must-be-constant-expression

Answer (score 18):

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
       {
           radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   }
   );
```

Comment: Better answer than the accepted one, IMHO

Comment: That would be like this in kotlin and using binding. But it doesn't change anything if done with findViewById, it would just be `findViewById<RadioGroup>`. And the same for MaterialRadioButton, I use that one because I'm using material components, but it can be changed by RadioButton
`radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
    val radioButton = findViewById<RadioButton>(checkedId)
    Toast.makeText(this, radioButton.text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}`

Answer (score 13):

```
int genid=gender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(genid);
String gender=radioButton.getText().toString();
```

Hope this works. You can convert your output to string in the above manner.
`gender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();` - gender is the id of RadioGroup.

Comment: works fine! but when I save the data into firebase and if I miss any Radio btn to check app crashed with "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.RadioButton.getText()' on a null object reference" any solution

Comment: maybe no radion button is selected, check radioButton != null before calling getText()

Answer (score 9):

```
mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)group.findViewById(checkedId);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who is populating programmatically and looking to get an index, you might notice that the checkedId changes as you return to the activity/fragment and you re-add those radio buttons.  One way to get around that is to set a tag with the index:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < myNames.length; i++) {
        rB = new RadioButton(getContext());
        rB.setText(myNames[i]);
        rB.setTag(i);
        myRadioGroup.addView(rB,i);
    }
```

Then in your listener:

```
    myRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
            int mySelectedIndex = (int) radioButton.getTag();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

just use `getCheckedRadioButtonId()` function to determine wether if anything is checked, if `-1` is the `return` value, you can avoid showing toast

Answer (score 4):

```
Radiogroup rgteam;
String team;
rgteam.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {
            RadioButton rb= (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
            team = rb.getText().toString();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

RadioGroup in XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Java"/>

    </RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="Select Your Course"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/txtView"/>
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/rdGroup"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtView">
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdbJava"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:text="Java"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdbPython"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:text="Python"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdbAndroid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:text="Android"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdbAngular"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:text="AngularJS"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/getBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rdGroup"
        android:text="Get Course" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RadioButton android, java, angular, python;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        android = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rdbAndroid);
        angular = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rdbAngular);
        java = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rdbJava);
        python = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rdbPython);
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getBtn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String result = "Selected Course: ";
                result+= (android.isChecked())?"Android":(angular.isChecked())?"AngularJS":(java.isChecked())?"Java":(python.isChecked())?"Python":"";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
        String str="";
        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.rdbAndroid:
                if(checked)
                str = "Android Selected";
                break;
            case R.id.rdbAngular:
                if(checked)
                str = "AngularJS Selected";
                break;
            case R.id.rdbJava:
                if(checked)
                str = "Java Selected";
                break;
            case R.id.rdbPython:
                if(checked)
                str = "Python Selected";
                break;
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot to Chris.

This is my solution:

```
RadioGroup radgroup_opcionesEventos = null;


 private static String[] arrayEventos = {
            "Congestión", "Derrumbe", "Accidente"
    };
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        radgroup_opcionesEventos = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg_opciones_evento);
        int i=0;//a.new.ln
        for(String evento : arrayEventos) {
            //RadioButton nuevoRadio = crearRadioButton(evento);//a.old.ln
            RadioButton nuevoRadio = crearRadioButton(evento,i);//a.new.ln
            radgroup_opcionesEventos.addView(nuevoRadio,i);
        }

        RadioButton primerRadio = (RadioButton) radgroup_opcionesEventos.getChildAt(0);
        primerRadio.setChecked(true);
}

private RadioButton crearRadioButton(String evento, int n)
    {
        //RadioButton nuevoRadio = new RadioButton(this);//a.old.ln
        RadioButton nuevoRadio = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());//a.new.ln

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        nuevoRadio.setLayoutParams(params);
        nuevoRadio.setText(evento);
        nuevoRadio.setTag(evento);
        return nuevoRadio;
    }


@Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        radgroup_opcionesEventos.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
                //int mySelectedIndex = (int) radioButton.getTag();
                String mySelectedIndex = radioButton.getTag().toString();
            }
        });
        super.onResume();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I have had problems getting radio buttons id's as well when the RadioButtons are dynamically generated.  It does not seem to work if you try to manually set the ID's using `RadioButton.setId()`.  What worked for me was to use `View.getChildAt()` and `View.getParent()` in order to iterate through the radio buttons and determine which one was checked.  All you need is to first get the RadioGroup via `findViewById(R.id.myRadioGroup)` and then iterate through it's children.  You'll know as you iterate through which button you are on, and you can simply use `RadioButton.isChecked()` to determine if that is the button that was checked.

Comment: If you check chinna's answer, that page _is_ linked

Comment: @AbrahamUribe can you review my edited answer and see if it's better than the previous one that was flagged?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar you are correct, I did not notice the link in the original answer, that is my mistake.

Comment: For this case, I believe the better solution is to use setTag(i), where i is the index of the array you're using to populate the radio group.  I added an answer to show that way of doing it.