# not able to get vaule from RadioButtons

Tags: java, android

i m trying to get the Value from RadioButton that is Created by String of Array 
i m using OClickListener() to get the Value from RadioButton but Error is showing
**" java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioButton
"**

Here is my Code,Please check

```html
for(int i =0; i<ab.length;i++)
{
RadioButton radioButtonView = new RadioButton(this);
radioButtonView.setText(ab[i]);
radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView, p);
}
       
Button btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v)
    {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 // get selected radio button from radioGroup
 int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
 // find the radiobutton by returned id
    String s = ((RadioButton) v ).getText().toString();
 Toast.makeText(Radio_Button.this, "This is: " + s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

and LogCat is

```js
   
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.radiobuttondynamic, PID: 4741
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioButton
  at com.example.radiobuttondynamic.Radio_Button$1.onClick(Radio_Button.java:64)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please Give Suggestion to Correct it

thanks 
thanks

Comment: You can refer to this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179124/android-getting-value-from-selected-radiobutton

Comment: The problem is that you are casting the v into radio button but it  actually a button. use this as a sample code. View radioButton = radioButtonGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID); if you have any query please comment.

Comment: @Vivek cau please tell me where i have to write this line of code?

Comment: @Ashu,I posted my answer. Please refer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to cast the button to radio button??
anyway if you want to get the text of selected radio button do the following

```
btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{

  RadioButton selectedButton=   (RadioButton)findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());  //you will get the selected radiobutton here

 String s=selectedButton..getText().toString();
 Toast.makeText(Radio_Button.this, "This is: " + s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: it's not working can u please suggest any thing other ,Please

Comment: it is not showing any Error. but it is not getting the Value of RadioButton

Comment: glad it worked! did you find out what was the error?

Comment: yes, it was my messed so that i started from new Activity thanks

Answer (score 2):

`v` is a `Button` and you cast it to `RadioButton` in this line:

```
String s = ((RadioButton) v ).getText().toString();
```

try this:

if you added `radioButton` programmatically you can `setID` to `radioButtons`:

```
for(int i =0; i<ab.length;i++)
{
RadioButton radioButtonView = new RadioButton(this);
radioButtonView.setText(ab[i]);
radioButtonView.setID(i);
radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView, p);
}
```

and then

```
 String s = ((RadioButton) findViewById(yourRadioButtonID) ).getText().toString();
```

Comment: i tried it but not working, please suggest any other solution. Looking for hlep

Comment: what is **"Hamidreza Samadi"** ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
String s = radioButtonView.getText().toString();
```

Instead of:

```
String s = ((RadioButton) v ).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score -1):

I am writing the onclick functionality.

```
public void onClick(View v)
 {

  int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    if(selectedId !=-1)
     {    
        View radioButton = radioGroup.findViewById(selectedId );
        int radioId = radioGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);
        RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(radioId);
        String selection = (String) btn.getText();
    Toast.makeText(Radio_Button.this, "This is: " + s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }   
 }
```

Try this, If you have any problem then please comment.

Comment: what is rg1 ? is it any Reference

Comment: Hi Ashu, i edited my answer. Please refer that if your problem still not solved. Thanks.

Comment: This is correct. Go and check here.. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html radioGroup is ViewGroup.