# Android Radio Button Group with EditText imbedded

Tags: java, android

my problem is that I want a Radio Group that has 3 Radio Buttons, using the scheme below.
The three choices are:
1. [] Male
2. [] Female
3. [] Custom: (self-described identity)

However, the problem is that I want the user to type in their self-described identity into an EditText for me to retrieve.

So the following code is from my XML page, with some elements blocked out by "####".

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="####"
    android:id="@+id/male_female_custom_choice"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_button_male"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_button_male"
        android:checked="true" />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_button_female"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_button_female"
        android:checked="false" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="####"
        android:weightSum="1">
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_button_custom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/radio_button_custom"
                android:checked="false" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="####"
                android:hint="####"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1.05"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="42dp"
                android:layout_height="43dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="####"
                android:id="####"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RadioGroup>
```

As you can see, I have tried to use a LinearLayout to isolate the custom option.
However, there are unintended and undesired side effects.
1. The custom option can be selected in addition to the other 2 predefined genders.
2. The custom option cannot be selected on its own.

In the actual Java file for the activity, I have the following code:

```
// button, radio button, editText, and Spinner fields
public EditText mEdit;
public RadioButton rButton;
public RadioGroup rSexGroup;
rSexGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.male_female_custom_choice);
// get selected radio button from RadioGroup
int selectedId = rSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
// find radio button by returned id
rButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
// assign gender based on id of radio button
if (selectedId == 1) {
    pat.gender = "male";
}
if (selectedId == 2) {
    pat.gender = "female";
}
if (selectedId == 3) {
    mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.####);
    pat.gender = (mEdit.getText().toString());
}
```

Since I am a bit rusty with Java, it may be possible that I have some really newbish errors. Please advise.

Once again, I am looking for a way to get a set of 3 RadioButtons, each on an individual line, with the last RadioButton with an EditText adjacent to it from which I obtain the desired information.

EDIT: Here's a picture of what I want it to look like:
(http://i68.tinypic.com/ao2oow.png)

Unfortunately I need 10 reputation to post images. :(

Mohit's answer gives the EditText on a different line than the custom input.
(http://i63.tinypic.com/68u88x.png)

Please note that the orientation of the EditText is adjacent to the custom, and not below. I apologize for not clearly specifying enough what I wanted.

Comment: where is the link or code ?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IwIErvZ7NBiqZ3e6ZHqQn_ajUihU3GB7gfCHUhSuDbQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gwBU031O1y6hGCjnc3hdrdLz93gpGAZ0iIYROqnrrkg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Initially disable edit text .. when someone choose custom option from radio group enable edit text

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35239621/2826147

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Because `selectedId` will not be *1,2 or 3*....debug it you will get value..

> *The custom option cannot be selected on its own.*

2. Remove your 3rd `RadioButton` from `LinearLayout` and replace below 2nd `RadioButton` and put your `EditText` and `TextView` inside `LinearLayout`..

On you listener get `getCheckedRadioButtonId` and `getText()` of that `RadioButton` and check it accordingly...

I dont no what is your task but here is how can get all three `RadioButton` working and get custom text too....

xml...

**UPDATE**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.ex.MainActivity" >

 <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/male_female_custom_choice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_button_male"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Male" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_button_female"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="FeMale" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_button_custom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="Custom" />
</RadioGroup>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/male_female_custom_choice"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/male_female_custom_choice"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".8"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="aa"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="aaa"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/but"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/male_female_custom_choice"
    android:text="Get" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

.java file..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 public EditText mEdit;
 public RadioButton rButton;
 public RadioGroup rSexGroup;
 public Button but;
 public String str = "";

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rSexGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.male_female_custom_choice);
    but= (Button) findViewById(R.id.but);

    but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int selectedId = rSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            rButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
            if (rButton.getText().toString().equals("Male")) {
                str = "Male";
            }
            if (rButton.getText().toString().equals("FeMale")) {
                str = "FeMale";
            }
            if (rButton.getText().toString().equals("Custom")) {
                mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
                str = mEdit.getText().toString();
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

you can also set visibility of `LinearLayout` so that it only visible when custom in checked....

Hope it help..

Comment: I can understand the reasoning behind the java code and it is very helpful. However, the XML code does not suit my purposes (I have attached pictures to show what I want, and compared to what is displayed from your XML code). Is there a way to adjust the code and move the elements around so that it is more compact like my desired display?

Comment: The problem with the RelativeLayout seems to be that I can't put the EditText on the same line as the "Custom" RadioButton. I was looking for a way to put them on the same line.

Comment: you can achieve you want (in picture) by putting LinearLayout Rightof Radiobutton and alignBottom with it....

Comment: yes, thank you. I've marked it with a check mark.

I have a different problem though that's related... if I add more info/text to the Male/Female Options, the space provided for the EditText decreases, which is something I don't really want.

[] Male (****************info***************) << line 1
[] Female (********* more info **********) << line 2
[] Custom (____edittext____)(**info**) << line 3

is what I'm aiming for. However, since you've answered my question and resolved one of the problems listed, I gave you the green check mark. :)

Comment: Yes, that is correct but the textview forces a lack of space for the edittext.
To be precise, I get an onMeasure error even though I modify the text size to be small.

Comment: you might be having large text

Comment: If I could make the LinearLayout a bit smaller, I might be able to fit it in.

Comment: you can define the width,height?

Comment: Yes, I got exactly what I was looking for now, thank you for your help and patience!

Answer (score 1):

- put radio group in `RelativeLayout`
- set third `radiobutton` text as empty/null
- add `EditText` as `layout_alignParentBottom="true"`
- now programmatically call EditText's `onFocusChangeListener`

  ```
  edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

      @Override

      public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
          if(b)
            thirdRadio.setCheched(true);
      }
  });
  ```