# Radio Button and TextField Android-studio

Tags: android-studio

How can I make a radio button group and a TextField, so that whenever I click on TextField the radio button automatically changes from one to another?
Please give me a block of code for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307543/android-radio-button-group-with-edittext-imbedded check this

Comment: Sorry but this not helped me

Comment: Have you solved ??

Comment: no I want to make the radio button automatic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want the `radioButton` checked status change once the `textView` click. You can achieve by this way.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private RadioGroup radioSexGroup;
    private RadioButton radioSexButton,male,female;
    private TextView btnDisplay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        radioSexGroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        btnDisplay=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        male = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
        female=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);


        btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int selectedId=radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                radioSexButton=(RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
                if(radioSexButton.getText().toString().equals("Male"))
                {
                    female.setChecked(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    male.setChecked(true);
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:text="Male"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.13" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Me "
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"></TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks I will check it!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_radiogroup_control.htm

check this link , to use radio group with textviews