# Android CheckBox to show multiple selection of text in one string

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I have 7 checkboxes which shows week days,Now what i want to do is to store the text of each check box in single string on basis of selected checkbox.
What i am doing is by using **if else condition** but it is bit long.

Any help how i can minimize the code.

The code goes like this for every condition.

```
 if(mon.isChecked()&& tue.isChecked()){
       MON=mon.getText().toString();
       TUE=tue.getText().toString();
       text=MON+","+TUE;
   }
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35239621/2826147).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

`android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"` to your all check boxes

and 
write your **onCheckboxclicked()** as follows

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    // Is the view now checked?
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    // Check which checkbox was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.mon:
            if (checked)
                text = text + " mon";
            else
            break;
        case R.id.tue:
            if (checked)
                text = text + " tue";
            else
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You saved the day. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a onCheckBoxClickedListener and use a switch statement on the id.