# How to store Radio Button value in SqLite Database in Android.I'm using Radio Group

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm implementing `SQLite` Database in Android. I'm stuck at this point that how to store RadioButton's value in that database. I'm using `RadioGroup`. Please help me I'm a Beginner in Android Development.

Comment: Please post the code that you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have `myRadioGroup` as RadioGroup,

Now at first you have to get the `id` of the selected RadioButton like here

```
int id = myRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

Then after have to find the RadioButton by the id you got like

```
mySelectedRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);
```

Then get the text of it and save to sqlite

```
String mySelectedText = mySelectedRadioButton.getText().toString();
//Save the value to database
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to store an integer variable, which is modified by a RadioButton click? and then retrieve this "positional id" and use to re-check the RadioButton on the Activity reload?

Comment: @BobMalooga Yes that would be much better,  I thought S(he) is in confuse on getting the text so that I simply explained about it. He will definitely apply your idea when S(he) feels it's needed. I really appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: thank you sir. i got what you are saying but still confused with this.i want to perform gender operation.         int id=r1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if(id == 0)
        {
            String radioButtonText = rmale.getText().toString();
        }
        else
        {
            String radioButtonText = rfemale.getText().toString();
        }   i did this now what should i do?

Comment: @DhavalMistry have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179124/android-getting-value-from-selected-radiobutton).