# How to add the selected Radiobutton in an array in android

Tags: android

There is a question having 4 options(Radio buttons). I want to add the option of selected radio button into an array. ONLY the option of the selected radio button.
The Radio Group is having 4 radio buttons.

Comment: do you use RadioGroup or only RadioButtons ?

Comment: take radiogroup of four buttons. and from the object of radiogroup you will get the selected radio button.

Comment: There is a radiogroup having 4 radio buttons. Specify the code.

Comment: then check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18179176/5519005

Comment: I want to add the selected radio button in an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap all the radiobuttons in a `RadioGroup` and then set its `OnCheckedChangeListener`:

```
final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            View radioButton = group.findViewById(checkedId);
            // add radioButton to Your array
        }
    });
```

Note that this code will add to the array the selected radio button every time it gets selected. If you want to add it on a button click, you need to do it this way:

```
final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int checkedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        View radioButton = radioGroup.findViewById(checkedId);
        // add radioButton to Your array
    }
})
```