# Getting the string of a selected RadioButton in Android

Tags: android, radio-button

Recently I decided to develop an app in Android. I have used this forum and other tools online to teach myself how to develop a simple app that asks the user for their name and answer few questions. My aim to allow the user to send the answers to any email of their choice. So far I have been able to achieve this:

From: ********@gmail.com

To: ********@gmail.com

Subject: Survey result for John Doe

Name: John Doe

Question 1: true

End of Survey.

My aim is to include in the email not the state of question 1 (i.e. "True") but instead I want to show the answer of their question. For Example, Question 1: B. 26-35.

I have searched online for the past couple of days but I have been having issues to find some help as I'm still new to programming. The closest thing I came across was this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179124/android-getting-value-from-selected-radiobutton) but it is not what I'm looking for. Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.sampleupdrs;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }

    public void emailResult (View view)
    {
        EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_field);
        String name = nameField.getText().toString();

        RadioGroup radioQ1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_Q1);
        final RadioButton checkedRadioQ1 = (RadioButton) radioQ1.findViewById(radioQ1.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        boolean isCheckedRadioQ1 = checkedRadioQ1.isChecked();
        radioQ1.setOnCheckedChangeListener (new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            public void onCheckedChanged (RadioGroup group, int checkedQ1Id)
            {
                RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton)group.findViewById(checkedQ1Id);
                boolean isCheckedRadioQ1 = checkedRadioQ1.isChecked();
                if (isCheckedRadioQ1)
                {
                    tv.setText("Checked: " +checkedRadioButton.getText());
                }
            }
        });

        String resultsEmail = createEmailSummary(name, isCheckedRadioQ1);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Survery result for " + name);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, resultsEmail);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    private String createEmailSummary (String name, boolean isCheckedRadioQ1) {
        String resultsEmail = "Name: " + name;
        resultsEmail += "\nQuestion 1 " + isCheckedRadioQ1;
        resultsEmail += "\nEnd of Survey";
        return resultsEmail;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name_field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"/>

        <TextView
        android:text="@string/q1string"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"/>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_Q1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/q1b0_url"
                android:text="@string/q1b0string"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/q1b1_url"
                android:text="@string/q1b1string"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/q1b0_url"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:gravity="top" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/q1b2_url"
                android:text="@string/q1b2string"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/q1b1_url"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:gravity="top" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/q1b3_url"
                android:text="@string/q1b3string"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/q1b2_url"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:gravity="top" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/q1b4_url"
                android:text="@string/q1b4string"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/q1b3_url"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:gravity="start" />

        </RadioGroup>


        <TextView
            android:text="@string/q2string"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"/>

        <RadioGroup

    <Button
        android:text="Next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nextQ1"
        android:onClick="emailResult"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Survey</string>
    <string name="q1string">1. Select age group</string>
    <string name="q1b0string">A. 18-25</string>
    <string name="q1b1string">B. 26-35</string>
    <string name="q1b2string">C. 36-45</string>
    <string name="q1b3string">D. 46-59</string>
    <string name="q1b4string">E. 60+</string>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you need is `checkedRadioButton.getText().toString()` and not the boolean isCheckedRadioQ1.

Answer (score 1):

In `MainActivity` class,
you can get the text of the Radio button in this way:

```
boolean isCheckedRadioQ1 = checkedRadioQ1.isChecked();
text = "";
if (isCheckedRadioQ1) {
    text = checkedRadioQ1.getText().toString();
    tv.setText("Checked: " +checkedRadioButton.getText());
}
```

In method `createEmailSummary` do

```
resultsEmail += "\nQuestion 1 " + text;
```

instead of

```
resultsEmail += "\nQuestion 1 " + isCheckedRadioQ1
```

You'll have to send `text` as a parameter to `createEmailSummary` instead of `isCheckedRadioQ1`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I made all the changes that you suggested and now in the email I'm getting a blank space after Question 1. Should I declare text as String text =" "; under public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity.