# Error when clicking Group header in listview

Tags: android, listview

First of all sorry for having a big finger.

I have a `header.xml` and `detail.xml` that populating the my listview based on data. now I noticed on `Listivew` click event. If i click the Group Header in the `ListView` an error occurs. How can I fix it?

Here is my code.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    TextView pos_remarks = (view.findViewById(R.id.list_remarks));
   final String l_remarks = pos_remarks.getText().toString();
});
```

Forgot the error sorry

```
Process: com.main, PID: 5539
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.main.fragment.fragment_plan$1.onItemClick(fragment_plan.java:71)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:315)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1209)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3331)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4403)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:4103)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10062)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2776)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2408)
```

`Header.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/line_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="8sp"
        android:paddingLeft="25sp"
        android:paddingRight="25sp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:paddingTop="8sp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/tahoma"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`details.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4.5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_remarks"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="@font/tahoma"
            android:paddingLeft="5sp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>`
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace of the error.

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace from the error you mention to your question?

Comment: done adding the error

Comment: Is your `TextView` is null.

Comment: actually no. the error always happen when I click the layout from `header.xml` that has been added in my listview. I mean the group header

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376654/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-java-lang-charsequence-android-widget-textview)

Comment: Yes but when you click on it they try to find `R.id.list_remarks` and they surely return null.

Comment: yah thats the error and `R.id.list_remarks` is inside the `detail.xml` and when i click the `detail.xml` that has the data the error doesnt occured

Comment: Try to replace `view.findViewById(R.id.list_remarks)` by `findViewById(R.id.list_remarks)`

Comment: that one gave me an error

Comment: sure. for a moment

Comment: done adding the xml

Comment: I think this can help you to resolve the problem https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemIdAtPosition(int)

Comment: actually thats what im finding but i dont know how to implement it specially if i have multiple data in 1 row

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(pos_remarks!=null){
    final String l_remarks = pos_remarks.getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: you mean all of my views will be enclosed by that

Comment: you can use else block for other views

Comment: Can you explain *why* your code will help solve OP's problem? A block of code alone isn't all that informative