# Value and text on radio botton android studio

Tags: android, xml

I am wondering when i use radio button and make a different value and text when it show. like html.

Example (Html):

```
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> MAN<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> FEMALE<br>
</form>
```

Like that, the value is "male" and the text is "MAN", how it will be when i use radio botton on android studio, because i just know this code :

```
  <RadioGroup
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/text"
android:id="@+id/myRadioGroup"
android:background="#abf234"
android:checkedButton="@+id/gender" >

  <RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/male"
    android:text="MALE" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/female"
    android:text="FEMALE" />
```

so on the android we just know the text (text will be display on the screen) and the value is same, my question is how if i want get a value like "male" but text show on screen is "MAN" like html.

Comment: like this **`android:text="MALE"`** or **`android:text="FEMALE"`**

Comment: what about the value?? @Nilu

Comment: In android value like HTML is not used. to get access for radio button `android:id="@+id/radioButton2"` is used.

Comment: @RizalAhmad you get values of radio button using **`ID`** of radio Button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android getting value from selected radiobutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179124/android-getting-value-from-selected-radiobutton)

Comment: i know how to get value of radion botton using id but the issue is i want get a value like "male" but text show on screen is "MAN" like html in my question. @Nilu

Answer (score 0):

There is no `value` for `RadioButton` in Android.

You can get the text using

```
myRadioButton.getText();
```

and state checked or not using

```
myRadioButton.isChecked();
```

which will return true or false depending on whether your RadioButton is checked or not.

> the value is "male" and the text is "MAN"

You can do:

```
String value = "";
if (rbTkiKG.getText().toString().equals("MAN")) {
    value = "male";
}
```

but as I have already said this is not quite required.

Comment: how if i want to make a different between a value and a text?

Comment: @RizalAhmad `how if i want to make a different between a value and a text?` - I don't get this, Maybe I can help you if I know what you are trying to achieve. If you want to change the text you can use `setText()` method like `setText("My new text");`

Comment: look at the html code, the value and the text is different, so i ask how i make a code radio botton like html in android?

Comment: @RizalAhmad as I wrote in the answer, `RadioButton`'s in Android are different from the one's in html, they don't have this value thing, after all it will as you expect a RadioButton to work, And why do you need the value for?

Comment: so your answer is impossible when i want get a value like "male" but text show on screen is "MAN" like html in my question?, i just need because i have a multiple choice of question but when people or user choice it i just need the abbreviation of that answer

Comment: @RizalAhmad you need to change the way you think of RadioButtons in Android, if you really want that you can get the text and assign a local variable value.

Comment: i just ask, so do you think it's impossible?

Answer (score 0):

in **html** we use value and in android we use id instead of
 Try this code for `RadioButton`

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text"
    android:id="@+id/myRadioGroup"
    android:background="#abf234"
    android:checkedButton="@+id/gender" >

      <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/male"
        android:text="MALE" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/female"
        android:text="FEMALE" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Male"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Female"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textSize="25dp"/>

  </RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this Help.

Comment: how about the VALUE? i want get a value like "male" but text show on screen is "MAN" like html in my question.

Comment: you can get value of that radio button by doing below code.`int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            // find the radiobutton by returned id
            radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

            Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
                radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: i know how to get value of radion botton using id but the issue is i want get a value like "male" but text show on screen is "MAN" like html in my question.

Comment: why you need value?

Comment: i just need because i have a multiple choice of question but when people or user choice it i just need the abbreviation of that answer