# How to handle dynamically added radiobutton check and uncheck in android

Tags: android, radio-button

I have crated 4 radiobutton in recyclerview but when i check one it checked but when i checked another one radiobutton then first one can not be unchecked

```
 holder.cb_votes.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                for (int i = 0; i < pollItems.size(); i++) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        holder.cb_votes.setChecked(true);

                    } else {
                        holder.cb_votes.setChecked(false);
                    }


                }
            }
        });
```

this is my xml

```
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rg_cb_votes"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/cb_votes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="Yes"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

        </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Create RadioGroup, and add radiobuttons into RadioGroup

Comment: you used radiobutton into radiogroup.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179124/android-getting-value-from-selected-radiobutton

Comment: i have already used radio group to radiobutton

Answer (score 0):

Radiobutton in wikipedia says:

> A radio button or option button is a type of graphical user interface element that allows the user to choose only one of a predefined set of options.

You would have to just use **checkboxes** instead of radio button for allowing multiple options to be selected,else you are doing something which is inherently wrong in a UI be it mobile/web.

:-)