# I want only one of the radio buttons to be selected, that is, multiple selection shouldn't be allowed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/public_line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Public"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:text="Public"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/public_button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            />

        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="league is visible to the public,
                          that is, anyone can join your league"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Private"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:text="Private"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/private_button"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Only people with invite code can join"
            />
    </RadioGroup>
    <TextView
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/orange_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Done"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my layout. It allows both the radio buttons to be selected. Can someone help me figure out what the problem is? From what I know the problem is that the radio buttons are not directly in the radio group, but how am I supposed to accommodate them in the radio group directly to get this same layout. Else is there an alternate way to solve the problem

Comment: It seems duplicate. check this out  https://stackoverflow.com/a/18179176/4295522

Comment: @AchuthGovind You mean to say while maintaining the same design?

Comment: You might want to write some custom logic in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Your radioButtons must be exaclly child of RadioGroup like this

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

 </RadioGroup>
```

But in your case is child of linearlayout and each radio button can selecteable

Answer (score 0):

The `RadioButton`s have to be direct childs of `RadioGroup` to have it automatically manage the single selection.
From your layout it seems you are trying to display text to the side of your `RadioButton`s. To do so you can simply set the attribute `android:text` on the `RadioButton`, no need to use additional `TextView`s.

Answer (score 0):

**just simply try this one**

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radio1">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Public"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Public"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/public_button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:checked="true"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="league is visible to the public,
                      that is, anyone can join your league"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Public"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Private1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:text="Private"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/private_button2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:checked="true"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Only people with invite code can join"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Private1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve your solutions

First is that RadioButtons set directly childs of RadioGroup like below

```
<RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/public_button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            />


         <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/private_button"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                />
</RadioGroup>
```

Second solution is if you don't set RadioButtons set directly childs of RadioGroup than you should add some code to your java file like below:

```
 publicButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    publicButton.setChecked(true);
                    privateButton.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });
privateButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked){
                            publicButton.setChecked(false);
                            privateButton.setChecked(true);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Where privateButton and publicButton are radio buttons.

I hope its work for you.