# How to get text of the checked id from radio group using view binding?

Tags: android, android-studio, radio-button, radio-group, android-viewbinding

I had gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179124/android-getting-value-from-selected-radiobutton) and found a common answer i.e

```
        int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

        Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
            radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But how to get text using view binding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this:

EDIT:

```
int id = binding.radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
RadioButton radioButton = binding.getRoot().findViewById(id);
//Then get the radio button's text
Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
        radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: getViewById didn't worked (shows error)

Comment: Try findViewById instead

Answer (score 0):

To find the text of a selected radio button in Kotlin for Android, you can follow these steps:

1. Declare a reference to the radio group in your activity or fragment. For example, if your radio group has an ID of `radioGroup`, you can declare it as follows:

```
val radioGroup = findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.radioGroup)
```

2.Set a listener on the radio group to detect when a radio button is selected. You can use the setOnCheckedChangeListener method to achieve this:

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
val selectedRadioButton = findViewById<RadioButton>(checkedId)
val selectedText = selectedRadioButton.text.toString()
// Use the selectedText as needed
```

}

1. Inside the listener, retrieve the selected radio button using the provided `checkedId`  parameter. Then, you can access the text of the selected radio button using the text property, and convert it to a string using `.toString()`
   The selectedText variable will contain the text of the selected radio button, which you can use as needed in your application.

Remember to replace  `R.id.radioGroup` with the actual `ID` of your radio group in your layout file.