# adding other library crashes other one

Tags: android, android-library

I try to add facebookSDK library to my project and everything crashed. Firstly appear the problem that I have 3 version of `android-support-v4.jar`, so I copied the file from my project and paste it in other 2 direction. Then I get the problem with the action bar buttons like something wrong was with these library, I remove all files and add it one more time.

Now I have error in every single case

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{ 
    Intent  intent;
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
 here ->    case R.id.Choice1:
        intent= new Intent(this, Chooser.class);

        startActivity(intent);

        return true;
```

like he didn't see the items from menu. 
I have to add `android-support-v4.jar` one more time ?

Comment: I changed every switch statement to if-else ones and I haven't got errors now, somebody knows the source of this problem

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: "case expressions must be constant expressions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the switch/case statement with if/else. You can just click on switch and then press CTRL+1 if you're in Eclipse.

check this question for more info [switch case statement error: case expressions must be constant expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092712/switch-case-statement-error-case-expressions-must-be-constant-expression)

Comment: Yeah it works but I'm curious about the source of this problem. yesterday it worked with switch statement and everything was ok