# source code error in mobile backend starter of google app engine---android client

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I have followed the steps in mobile backend starter in google app engine, and use the sample "guestbook" provided, but after building all the projects, it shows several errors which seems to me the source code errors as follows:

1.Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
case expressions must be constant expressions   GuestbookActivity.java  /CloudBackendAndroidClient/src/com/google/cloud/backend/sample/guestbook    line 146    Java Problem

2.Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
case expressions must be constant expressions   IntroFirstFragment.java /CloudBackendAndroidClient/src/com/google/cloud/backend/sample/guestbook    line 50 Java Problem

3.Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
case expressions must be constant expressions   IntroSecondFragment.java    /CloudBackendAndroidClient/src/com/google/cloud/backend/sample/guestbook    line 53 Java Problem

4.Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
case expressions must be constant expressions   IntroSecondFragment.java    /CloudBackendAndroidClient/src/com/google/cloud/backend/sample/guestbook    line 56 Java Problem

5.Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
case expressions must be constant expressions   IntroThirdFragment.java /CloudBackendAndroidClient/src/com/google/cloud/backend/sample/guestbook    line 60 Java Problem

6.Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
case expressions must be constant expressions   IntroThirdFragment.java /CloudBackendAndroidClient/src/com/google/cloud/backend/sample/guestbook    line 63 Java Problem

7.Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
case expressions must be constant expressions   IntroThirdFragment.java /CloudBackendAndroidClient/src/com/google/cloud/backend/sample/guestbook    line 66 Java Problem

I definitely can't figure out what happends here, I don't know if there is any problem in its source code, so I need experts to help me to this problem.  Thanks so much!

---

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Ok, the problem is fixed as suggested. But a final problem is the error:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'parentActivityName' in package 'android' AndroidManifest.xml /CloudBackendAndroidClient  line 22 Android AAPT Problem

If I need to add something in androidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it is related to this post: [switch case statement error: case expressions must be constant expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092712/switch-case-statement-error-case-expressions-must-be-constant-expression)

It seems as of ADT 14 constants in the resource R class are no longer declared as final, so you will need to convert the switches into if-else statements.

Comment: but it seems to me hard to think google has not modified this , if it is this problem, since MBS is a new product.