# Android Java: is this a good way instead enums?

Tags: java, android, enums

I have to implement some classes with functions. These functions have to return some errors codes, I usually use to declare a public enum with the errors codes and that work for me (for example in c#) but I had read that enums are not so good in Android (performance), so what do you think about this code?

```
public class myClass_1
{
public final class myErrorCodes
{
    public static final int ERROR_1 = 0x01;
    public static final int ERROR_2 = 0x02;
    public static final int ERROR_3 = 0x03;
    public static final int ERROR_4 = 0x04;
    public static final int ERROR_5 = 0x05;
    public static final int ERROR_6 = 0x06;
}

public int Function_1(int a,int b)
{
    // do something here...

    return myErrorCodes.ERROR_1;
}
}
```

Comment: Not so sure Enums are bad (anymore), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143256/why-was-avoid-enums-where-you-only-need-ints-removed-from-androids-performanc

Answer (score 4):

The enum performance warning was removed from the documentation.

See: [Why was "Avoid Enums Where You Only Need Ints" removed from Android's performance tips?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143256/why-was-avoid-enums-where-you-only-need-ints-removed-from-androids-performanc)

Answer (score 0):

There is not any problems with enums [now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143256/why-was-avoid-enums-where-you-only-need-ints-removed-from-androids-performanc). So, you can use it if you want.

Code with ints will work slightly faster - but you will neve see it :)