# Enum State pattern for android

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, enums, state-pattern

I'm trying to create a Enum STATE pattern so I can set the current state of my operations.
In C# (i think) I used this pattern:

```
Enum State { STARTED, STOPPED, PAUSED };
State _s;

public foo() {
   _s = State.STARTED;
}
```

I did read somewhere that you shouldn't or couldn't use Enum in Android. How can I replicate this design pattern in Android?

Comment: Enums are slightly less efficient than ints, but it probably won't be a big enough difference to matter. Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: I'm not so sure that you can't use enums for Android. That information might be obsolete due to performance gains of the VM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143256/why-was-avoid-enums-where-you-only-need-ints-removed-from-androids-performanc

Comment: Okey, that actually answerd my question. Thanks alot @Blacklight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely can use them. Android's libraries don't which probably perpetuates the myth/out of date advice. It's easy to switch from one to the other, so start with enums and only change if you experience performance issues, but I doubt you will.

Comment: Yes it worked like a charm. For future readers: `private static enum State {STARTED, STOPPED, RESETED};
 private State state;` and to set the state `state = State.STARTED;`