# Applying enum consist of 3 adapters between 2 activities in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-activity, enums, kotlin, baseadapter

I wonder if somebody can help me to solve enum problem for represent 2 object inside `Main2Activity.kt`?

I have 2 activities to connect between the:
The first activity for Grid View `MainActivity.kt`, second for List View `Main2Activity.kt`and I have 3  object instance (`adapter`) from `MainActivity.kt` and (`adapter1`,`adapter2`) from `Main2Activity.kt` and i wanna pass specific object instance when click on specific image in the `MainActivity.kt`

Note: I'm using `BaseAdapter`.

**Here is a MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var adapter:FoodAdapter?=null
var listOfFoods =ArrayList<Food>()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(layout.activity_main)


    // load foods
    listOfFoods.add(Food("Coffee","   Coffee preparation is", a))
    listOfFoods.add(Food("Coffee","   Coffee preparation is", b))
    listOfFoods.add(Food("Coffee","   Coffee preparation is", c))
    listOfFoods.add(Food("Coffee","   Coffee preparation is", d))

    adapter= FoodAdapter(this,listOfFoods)

    gvListFood.adapter =adapter

}


class  FoodAdapter: BaseAdapter {
    var listOfFood= ArrayList<Food>()
    var context: Context?=null
    constructor(context:Context,listOfFood:ArrayList<Food>):super(){
        this.context=context
        this.listOfFood=listOfFood
    }
    override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View? {
        val food = this.listOfFood[p0]
        var inflator = context!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        var foodView= inflator.inflate(layout.food_ticket,null)
        foodView.ivFoodImage.setImageResource(food.image!!)
        foodView.ivFoodImage.setOnClickListener {


            if (foodView.ivFoodImage.context!!.equals(a) ) {
                val intent = Intent(context, Main2Activity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(Main2Activity.EXTRA_ADAPTER_MODE, AdapterType.adapter1.ordinal)
                    intent.putExtra("name", food.name!!)
                    intent.putExtra("des", food.des!!)
                    intent.putExtra("image", food.image!!)

                    context!!.startActivity(intent)

            }
            else if (foodView.ivFoodImage.context!!.equals(b)) {
                val intent = Intent(context, Main2Activity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(Main2Activity.EXTRA_ADAPTER_MODE, AdapterType.adapter2.ordinal)
                    intent.putExtra("name", food.name!!)
                    intent.putExtra("des", food.des!!)
                    intent.putExtra("image", food.image!!)
                    context!!.startActivity(intent)

           }
        }
        return foodView
    }

    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
        return listOfFood[p0]
    }

    override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
        return p0.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {

        return listOfFood.size
    }

}
}
```

**Here is a Main2Activity.kt**

```
class Main2Activity : AppCompatActivity() {
companion object {
    val EXTRA_ADAPTER_MODE = "extra_adapter_mode"
}
var adapter1: FoodAdapter? = null
var adapter2: FoodAdapter2? = null
var listOfFoods2 = ArrayList<Food>()
var listOfFoods3 = ArrayList<Food>()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)


    val bundle = intent?.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ADAPTER_MODE, AdapterType.adapter.ordinal)
    val adapterType = bundle?.let { AdapterType.fromOrdinal(it) }



   // val bundle = intent.extras
    val name = bundle.getString("name")
    val des = bundle.getString("des")
    val image = bundle.getInt("image")




    ivFoodImage2?.let {
        it.setImageResource(image)
    }

    tvName2?.let {
        it.text = name
    }

    tvDes2?.let {
        it.text = des
    }






    // load foods2
    listOfFoods2.add(Food("Coffee", "   Coffee1 preparation is", R.drawable.a))
     listOfFoods2.add(Food("Coffee", "   Coffee2 preparation is", R.drawable.b))

         //listOfFoods2.add(Food("Coffee","   Coffee preparation is",R.drawable.c))
         //listOfFoods2.add(Food("Coffee","   Coffee preparation is",R.drawable.d))


    // load foods3


    //listOfFoods3.add(Food("Coffee","   Coffee preparation is",R.drawable.a))
    //listOfFoods3.add(Food("Coffee","   Coffee preparation is",R.drawable.b))
    listOfFoods3.add(Food("Coffee", "   Coffee3 preparation is", R.drawable.c))
    listOfFoods3.add(Food("Coffee", "   Coffee4 preparation is", R.drawable.d))



   if(adapter1 ==lvFoods2.adapter) {
       adapter1 = FoodAdapter(listOfFoods2, this)
       lvFoods2.adapter = adapter1
    } else if (adapter2==lvFoods2.adapter) {
       adapter2 = FoodAdapter2(listOfFoods3, this)
       lvFoods2.adapter = adapter2
     }

    }


class FoodAdapter : BaseAdapter {
    var context: Context? = null
    var listOfFoodsLocal2 = ArrayList<Food>()

    constructor(listOfFoods2: ArrayList<Food>, context: Context) : super() {
        this.listOfFoodsLocal2 = listOfFoods2
        this.context = context
    }

    override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
        val food = this.listOfFoodsLocal2[p0]
        var inflator = context!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val foodView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.food_ticket2, null)


        foodView.ivFoodImage2?.let {
            it.setImageResource(food.image!!)
                 }
        foodView.tvName2?.let {

            it.text = food.name!!
        }
        foodView.tvDes2?.let {
            it.text = food.des!!
        }

        foodView.ivFoodImage2.setOnClickListener {

            //move to next
            val intent = Intent(context, FoodDetails::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("name", food.name!!)
            intent.putExtra("des", food.des!!)
            intent.putExtra("image", food.image!!)

            context!!.startActivity(intent)

        }
        return foodView

    }


    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
        return listOfFoodsLocal2[p0]
    }

    override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
        return p0.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return listOfFoodsLocal2.size
    }

}

class FoodAdapter2 : BaseAdapter {
    var context: Context? = null
    var listOfFoodsLocal3 = ArrayList<Food>()

    constructor(listOfFoods3: ArrayList<Food>, context: Context) : super() {
        this.listOfFoodsLocal3 = listOfFoods3
        this.context = context
    }

    override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
        val food = this.listOfFoodsLocal3[p0]
        var inflator = context!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val foodView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.food_ticket2, null)


         foodView.ivFoodImage2?.let {
             it.setImageResource(food.image!!)
         }
        foodView.tvName2?.let {
            it.text = food.name!!
        }
         foodView.tvDes2?.let {
             it.text = food.des!!
         }



        foodView.ivFoodImage2.setOnClickListener {

            //move to next
            val intent = Intent(context, FoodDetails::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("name", food.name!!)
            intent.putExtra("des", food.des!!)
            intent.putExtra("image", food.image!!)

            context!!.startActivity(intent)

        }
        return foodView

    }


    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
        return listOfFoodsLocal3[p0]
    }

    override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
        return p0.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return listOfFoodsLocal3.size
    }

}
}
```

**Here is enum class**

```
enum class AdapterType {
    adapter,
    adapter1,
    adapter2;


    companion object {
        fun fromOrdinal(ordinal: Int): AdapterType? {
            return AdapterType.values().firstOrNull { it.ordinal == ordinal }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: first activity image]

[image: adapters enum class]

[image: 2nd activity image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to send it in your bundle like the other informations

```
intent.putExtra(Main2Activity.EXTRA_ADAPTER_MODE, AdapterType.ADAPTER_TYPE_1.toOrdinal())
```

and then get it from the bundle in your second Activity

```
val adapterTypeOrdinal = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ADAPTER_MODE, 0) // 0 is the default value
val type = AdapterType.fromOrdinal(adapterTypeOrdinal)
```

Comment: thank you for answer but how can i use the method `toOrdinal()` because i don't have it in my enum class i have only `ordinal`, please can you check my pictures ?

Comment: for the second part of your answer getIntExtra doesn't work so i change it  to `getBundle` please can you check 2nd activity picture ?

Comment: sorry, I think it is getIntent().getIntExtra

Comment: Thank you so much @Nino Handler, your answer really helped me alot, please, can you do last favor for me? and check this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46536953/many-listview-and-each-one-contains-different-objects-in-kotlin)