# How to use StringDef or IntDef in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations

Referring to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/StringDef
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/IntDef

I could easily create my compile validation which limits my String parameter to specific type of String (in Java)

e.g.

```
import android.support.annotation.StringDef;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.SOURCE;

@Retention(SOURCE)
@StringDef({
    "allow_one",
    "okay_two"
})
public @interface AllowedString { }
```

So if I have

```
class TestAnnotation(@AllowedString private val name: String) {
    fun printName(@AllowedString name: String) {}
}
```

And when I code

```
val testAnnotation = TestAnnotation("not_allowed")
```

Android Studio will flag error on the `not_allowed` as it is not in the list.

If I convert to Kotlin the `AllowedString` annotation interface as below, it doesn't works anymore. Why?

```
import android.support.annotation.StringDef
import java.lang.annotation.Retention
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.SOURCE

@Retention(SOURCE)
@StringDef("allow_one", "okay_two")
annotation class AllowedString
```

Why?

Comment: Seems to be a known issue: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/intdef-and-stringdef-not-being-checked-at-compile-time/7029, https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/resource-annotations-and-intdef-and-stringdef/1679, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833395/kotlin-annotation-intdef