# Kotlin type def

Tags: kotlin

I am trying IntDef typedef to restrict the specific type of parameter to the function. But when I am using IntDef using java it's working properly but at the same time, it's not working with kotlin. Below is my code snippet -

In JAVA -

```
@IntDef({CASH,WITHDRAW}) 
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE) 
public @interface TransTypeJava { 
int CASH = 1; int WITHDRAW = 2;
}
```

In Kotlin -

```
const val CASH = 1 const val WITHDRAW = 2 
@IntDef(CASH, WITHDRAW) 
@kotlin.annotation.Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE) 
internal annotation class TransTypeKotlin
```

Using in class -

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) 
demo(TransTypeJava.CASH)// Working 
demo(1) // Showing compile time error 
} 
fun demo(@TransTypeJava type:Int){}
```

Calling to the demo function gives me an error saying that Must be one of: 
`TransTypeJava.CASH`, `TransTypeJava.WITHDRAW` by passing value other than `TransTypeJava` type.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) 
demo(TransTypeKotlin.CASH) //Working 
demo(1) // Working 
} 
fun demo(@TransTypeKotlin type: Int){}
```

While using this with kotlin it does not show any error by passing value other than TransTypeKotlin type. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: same problem here , do you found any solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37839539/2736039 here is stated currently only in java

Answer (score -1):

Try out with this

```
@IntDef(MALE, FEMALE)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
annotation class UserRoleType {
    companion object {
        const val MALE = 1
        const val FEMALE = 2
    }
}
```

Comment: I used it in my live project and it's perfectly working for me. which type of error do you face while you use this?

Comment: Compiler doesn't shows me error even i am passing value other than specified type

Comment: strange!! Anyway, let me know if you need any help on that :)

Comment: Can you please share the pseudo code of function in which you have implemented this and also the code for calling the same function

Comment: private fun getUserType(userRoleType: Int){
        if(userRoleType == UserRoleType1.MALE){
            Log.d("Male", UserRoleType1.MALE.toString())
        }else if(userRoleType == UserRoleType1.FEMALE){
            Log.d("FEMALE", UserRoleType1.MALE.toString())
        }
    }


I called this function like this - getUserType(UserRoleType1.MALE)

Comment: In your case you have not specified the parameter type in the function.