# Error using IntDef defined in Kotlin when using in Java

Tags: java, kotlin, android-support-library

I'm trying to define an `IntDef` interface in Kotlin but then use those constants in Java. I am able to access it, but I get an IDE Lint error when I try to do a equals operator on it. Though, a different comparison operator (<, >) works fine. Even using 'Objects.equal()' works, just not ==. Anyone have any idea about this?

> Error: Must be one of: 1L, 2L

My Kotlin Class

```
class RandomClass{
    ...
    @IntDef(STATE_1, STATE_2)
    @Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
    annotation class MyState

    companion object {
        const val STATE_1 = 1L
        const val STATE_2 = 2L
    }
```

Accessing the Annotation in Java where Error Occurs

```
void myFunction(@RandomClass.MyState long state){
    if(state == RandomClass.STATE_1){
        ...
    }
}
```

My Temp Fix for this

```
void myFunction(@RandomClass.MyState long state){
    if(Objects.equal(state, RandomClass.STATE_1)){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error that you get?

Comment: No, on Java side it is only an IDE warning. On Kotlin, it is currently not supported. You have to always check for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Android Support typedef annotations in kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976002/how-to-use-android-support-typedef-annotations-in-kotlin)

Comment: @Cristan It isn't. This has to do with the equals operator in java when referring to an intdef defined in kotlin (which is possible).