# Enumerated annotation type in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

In java I can define enumerated annotation type like this (from [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-performance-avoid-using-enum-on-android-326be0794dc3))

```
// Constants
public static final String WINTER = "Winter";
public static final String SPRING = "Spring";
public static final String SUMMER = "Summer";
public static final String FALL = "Fall";

// Declare the @ StringDef for these constants:
@StringDef({WINTER, SPRING, SUMMER, FALL})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Season {}
```

What is Kotlin version of this code?

I have a problem when using this (straight conversion using IDE)

```
// Constants
private const val WINTER = "Winter"
private const val SPRING = "Spring"
private const val SUMMER = "Summer"
private const val FALL = "Fall"

// Declare the @ StringDef for these constants:
@StringDef(WINTER, SPRING, SUMMER, FALL)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
annotation class Season
```

as I cannot access e.g. Season.WINTER

Comment: Where are you trying to access to Season.Winter?. If it is a private constant, you will not be able to access it from outside the class.

Comment: Also you can try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976002/how-to-use-android-support-typedef-annotations-in-kotlin/38537175#38537175)

Comment: in java I can acces it like this Season.Winter anywhere

Comment: Yes, because you set it to public in Java.

Comment: :D @MiguelIsla, let me check if this is the reason that causes problems

Comment: also thanks for the link, I couldn't find it anywhere

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin you're better off using `enum class`. I had many problems converting `@IntDef` and `@StringDef` usages in Kotlin.

```
enum class Season constructor(val value: String) {
  WINTER("Winter"),
  SPRING("Spring"),
  SUMMER("Summer"),
  FALL("Fall");

  override fun toString(): String = value
}
```

Comment: isn't name final? Also, I am working on a library and I think it's still recommended to use enum annotation type instead of enums, so I would like to stick with that

Comment: I made it `val` so it's final yes, but that's up to you. Now if you don't want to use enum..

Comment: I mean IDE shows me an error "name in Enum is final and can't be overriden"

Comment: before adding override it was "name hides member of supertype and needs 'override' modifier"

Comment: Yeah ok, I was making that code out of my head, I fixed it. `name` was indeed reserved ;)